# Clear cells to right of selected cell in Excel VBA - Can't guess Column Letter Header

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have been able to successfully find the end of both a row and column, but I am only able to delete a column and not a row. The problem is that rows use numbers but my code is wanting a column letter. **My goal is to delete everything after cell A5 to the right.** Does anybody have any pointers?

Code:

```
Sub Range_End_Method()
'Finds the last non-blank cell in a single row or column

Dim lRow As Long
    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lRow & "")
    .Clear
End With

Dim lCol As Long
    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:???" & lCol & "")
   .Clear
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter) explains converting a column number to letter.

Comment: First, unless you're doing more than `.Clear` in the `With` just use `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & lRow).Clear` and note you do not need `& ""`. For your `???` use `Cells` and two argument `Range(<from>, <to>)` like this `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Cells(1, lCol ).Clear` . Cells takes either a column number or a string column letter as the column argument (the second argument).

Comment: It's not recommended to use Activeworkbook and/or Activesheet. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet1").Range("A1", Cells(1, lCol)).Clear

Comment: @busybyte That won't work with dynamically named sheets, I am aware of that "rule"

Comment: @TedD. I had a feeling I could use the Column # vs converting to a letter, but I had working code that I tweaked vs figuring that out, I will likely use your code and update an alternative/better method. I do like using `with` statements as I generally end up doing something else, but in this case your likely right, it could be a one liner. Thanks!

Comment: @TedD. there is a syntax error in your code, but busybyte code worked, except I used activeworkbook

Comment: Allow me to correct the second full code line of my previous comment. The `Cells` Object should be qualified with a sheet reference. Using `With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` , the With Block contains one statement `.Range("A1",  .Cells(1, lCol )).Clear` based on the OP code block.

Comment: For dynamic case: set MySheet1=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(dynamic1) or store the new sheet-name in a string: dynamic1= Newname1.

Comment: @busybyte I'm still working on functionality, then I will delve into cleaning the code, but thanks for the tip now I know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I knew there was a way, but couldn't figure it out, but Ted.D & BusyByte helped get me there, to not convert the column number to a letter. This code is simpler and works:

```
Sub Clear()

Dim lCol As Long
    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E5", Cells(1, lCol )).Clear

End Sub
```

This finds the last used column as a number then converts it to a letter and then deletes all cells after first hard coded cell to the right (last used column).

```
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function

Sub Range_End_Method()
Dim lCol As Long
    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    'but returns a NUMBER, that's what function Col_Letter converts to Letter
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A5:" & Col_Letter(lCol) & "1")
   .Clear
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: correct the syntax error inherited from my comment by using a a double closing parenthesis `Range("E5", Cells(1, lCol )).Clear` and if you qualifying Range, you should qualify Cells as well.